# Wordpress SQL attack...Unknown Javascript found on each post

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My site is redirecting to some malware induced site and after looking into my SQL database, I can see this js code in every single one of posts -  (Chrome throws a warning if you try and open this url) . It seems like I am not the only one http://wordpress.org/support/topic/was-my-site-just-hacked-found-random-script-in-all-pagesposts Kindly help if you can.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to check your plugins. If you have still no clue what could have caused it, you could take a look through the servers access logs, in that case it would help if you knew in what time frame this script was injected on your pages.

If you can't find anything suspicious in your logs either and you are on shared hosting, it's also possible that the attack was done on one of the other websites hosted on the same server.

Hope this helps you on the way a bit,
Cheers.

Comment: +1. I've been hearing about plugin vulnerabilities in Wordpress as a likely attack vector.